# How to use msbuild.exe cmd line in NANT using <exec program >

Tags: msbuild, nant

How to use msbuild.exe long cmd line using Nant script.MSBuild command is -->

```
<target name="publish-project-release-folder">
<exec program="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" verbose="true" >
<arg value="/target:Build;PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder" />
<arg value="/p:Configuration=Release;_PackageTempDir=C:\cicheckout\outdir\;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false" />
<arg value="C:\a\testteamcity\demo\WebApp\webapp.csproj" />
</exec>
```

```
Error : C:\245\hello.build(9,6):
'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.exe' is not a valid value   for attribute 'program' of <exec ... />.
Illegal characters in path.
Total time: 0 seconds.
```

Comment: What is the encoding used by your XML file? Although a long shot, try using this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Thnaks Nilay .I am not using any encoding --> <?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: Let me know if that works?

Comment: Hi Nilay, No luck . Any other solutions ???

Comment: Does it happen when you remove your arguments?

Comment: <target name="build-solution">  
<exec program="C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy.exe" verbose="true" >
  <arg value="-verb:sync" />
  <arg value="-source:contentPath='${src}'" /> 
  <arg value="-dest:contentPath='${dest}',ComputerName='${cn}',UserName='${un}',Password='${pw}',AuthType='Basic'" />
  <arg value="-EnableRule:DoNotDeleteRule" />
  <arg value="-allowUntrusted" />
  <arg value="–usechecksum" />
</exec>
</target>   and gives illegal characters in path

Comment: See the path `C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy.exe` and replace with `C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe`

Comment: Hi Nilay ! Let me check and update you ">" error! cheers

Comment: were you able to rectify this?

Comment: Hey Nilay! Thanks all sorted and my TeamCity server is working perfectly. Cheers!